# Solution for: Page.IsValid cannot be called before validation has taken place

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am using a wizard control in which I have a next button that has causes validation = true.  I also have a checkbox that when changed, in the event handler, I set causes validation = false for the next button.  When that button is clicked - I get the following:

Page.IsValid cannot be called before validation has taken place. It should be queried in the event handler for a control that has CausesValidation.

Here is the code:

```
protected void chk_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        ImageButton ibtnStepNext = (ImageButton)(this.WizardSummaryTemplate.CustomNavigationTemplateContainer.FindControl("StepNextButton"));

        ibtnStepNext.CausesValidation = (!chk.Checked);

    }
```

What would be the recommended solution to disabling validation for the next button so I don't see this error?

Comment: Are you calling `Page.IsValid` explicitly ?

Comment: yes - however, calling Page.Validate() before Page.IsValid doesn't solve my problem. And the method that calls Page.Validate() or Page.IsValid are not executed prior to this error.  It occurs in the initial post back of the checkbox check changed event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work around was to change the validation group for the button and it worked as expected.